# LogOff com registro em banco e exclusão de cookie atrás do Session_End() no Global.asax

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, cookies, injeção-de-dependência

Estou precisando de ajuda num projeto no qual estou a quebrar a cabeça faz dois dias. Estou a utilizar tecnologia Microsoft C# MVC5 e framework 4.5, utilizo também Entity Framework 6 com Repository Pattern, Unit of Work e Unity para a realização da injeção de dependência.

Tenho um controller chamado `AccountController` que é responsável por realizar o login e o logoff do usuário no sistema, este controller recebe os metodos de repository da aplicação pela injeção de dependência através do construtor do mesmo.

### AccountController

```
public class AccountController : BaseController
{
    private readonly IUsuarioApp _usuarioApp;
    private readonly IUnitOfWorkAsync _unitOfWorkAsync;

    public AccountController() { }

    public AccountController(IUsuarioApp usuarioApp, IUnitOfWorkAsync unitOfWorkAsync)
    {
        _unitOfWorkAsync = unitOfWorkAsync;
        _usuarioApp = usuarioApp;
    }

    // GET: Login
    [AllowAnonymous]
    public ActionResult Login()
    {
        return View();
    }

    //
    // POST: /Account/Login
    [HttpPost]
    [AllowAnonymous]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult Login([Bind(Include = "Email, Password")]LoginViewModel model, string returnUrl)
    {
        try
        {
            if (!ModelState.IsValid) return View(model);

            var usuarioAutenticado = _usuarioApp.AutenticarUsuarioPor(model.Email, model.Password);

            var logDeAcesso = new LogDeAcesso { DataDeAcesso = DateTime.Now, UsuarioId = usuarioAutenticado.Id };

            usuarioAutenticado.DataDoUltimoAcesso = logDeAcesso.DataDeAcesso;

            _usuarioApp.Update(usuarioAutenticado);
            _usuarioApp.GetRepository<LogDeAcesso>().Insert(logDeAcesso);
            _unitOfWorkAsync.SaveChanges();

            SessionContext.SetAuthenticationToken(usuarioAutenticado.Id.ToString(), false, ConvertToUsuarioViewModel(usuarioAutenticado));
            
            return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            ModelState.AddModelError("", "Tentativa de login inválido.");
            return View(model);
        }
    }

    public ActionResult LogOff(int id)
    {
        try
        {
            var ultimoLogsDeAcessoCriado = _usuarioApp.GetRepository<LogDeAcesso>().Query(model => model.UsuarioId == id).OrderBy(model => model.OrderByDescending(c => c.DataDeAcesso)).Select().FirstOrDefault();

            if (ultimoLogsDeAcessoCriado == null || ultimoLogsDeAcessoCriado.DataDeSaida != DateTime.MinValue) throw new Exception("Erro ao tentar deslogar do sistema.");

            ultimoLogsDeAcessoCriado.DataDeSaida = DateTime.Now;
            _usuarioApp.GetRepository<LogDeAcesso>().Update(ultimoLogsDeAcessoCriado);
            _unitOfWorkAsync.SaveChanges();

            FormsAuthentication.SignOut();
            Session.Clear(); //Pode não ser necessário, mas não é problemático o uso como prevenção
            Session.Abandon();

            //Limpar o cookie de Autenticação
            var resetFormsCookie = new HttpCookie(FormsAuthentication.FormsCookieName, "");
            resetFormsCookie.Expires = DateTime.Now.AddYears(-1);
            Response.Cookies.Add(resetFormsCookie);

            //Limpar a session cookie
            var resetSessionCookie = new HttpCookie("ASP.NET_SessionId", "");
            resetSessionCookie.Expires = DateTime.Now.AddYears(-1);
            Response.Cookies.Add(resetSessionCookie);

            //Invalida o Cache no lado do Cliente
            Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.NoCache);
            Response.Cache.SetNoStore();
            
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Danger("Error: " + ex.Message);
        }

        return RedirectToAction("Login", "Account");
    }


    #region Helpers
    
    private UsuarioViewModel ConvertToUsuarioViewModel(Usuario usuario)
    {
        return new UsuarioViewModel
        {
            Id = usuario.Id,
            Nome = usuario.Nome,
            UltimoAcesso = usuario.DataDoUltimoAcesso
        };
    }

    #endregion
}
```

Como é visto, ao logar é autenticado o usuário através do email e da senha, é criado uma instância do Log de Acesso onde cadastramos a data de entrada do acesso e posteriormente é criado o cookie onde ficará armazenado o cookie que permitirá o acesso as páginas do Site.

Depois de obter o acesso, o usuário pode clicar no botão logoff, no qual disparará o método `ActionResult LogOff` que obterá o ultimo log de acesso criado baseado no id do usuário, atualizará com o dado da Data de saída do sistema, limpará a Session e os Cookies, redirecionando ele para a página Login. A partir dai ele só terá acesso novamente as outras páginas caso ele realize o login novamente.

Está dinâmica funciona muito bem, mas tem um problema, e se o usuário não clicar no botão logoff, e invés disso, resolver fechar a aba ou o browser? Dá forma que foi construido, ele se manterá autenticado nos 20 min padrões q o IIS padroniza para tempo de inatividade, mas o tempo de expiração do cookie, sem falar que desta forma eu não poderei cadastrar a Data de Saída no Log de Acesso.

Pensando nisso eu configurei no Web.config um tempo de timeout da Session

Web.Config

```
<configuration>
  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5" />
    <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5" />
    <globalization culture="pt-BR" uiCulture="pt-BR" />
    <authentication mode="Forms">
      <forms loginUrl="~/Account/Login" timeout="2880" slidingExpiration="true" />
    </authentication>
    <sessionState
       mode="InProc"
       stateConnectionString="tcpip=127.0.0.1:42424"
       stateNetworkTimeout="20"
       sqlConnectionString="data source=127.0.0.1;Integrated Security=SSPI"
       sqlCommandTimeout="20"
       customProvider=""
       cookieless="UseCookies"
       cookieName="ASP.NET_SessionId"
       timeout="1"
       allowCustomSqlDatabase="false"
       regenerateExpiredSessionId="true"
       partitionResolverType=""
       useHostingIdentity="true">
      <providers>
        <clear />
      </providers>
    </sessionState>
    <machineKey validationKey="466AFE06F664B2E3662F97B81D30E87907F9921E51C95C618A670B396403AD98DD032BCE7610EEAE1FB1DA7B3ED7ACE56537E66FD6DF20E701351697E57C3D9C" decryptionKey="CD10ABC11246E6998AB7B9A8CC142CDD6C8AEF7FB12D15CF12158BEAD647C603" validation="SHA1" decryption="AES" /> 
  </system.web>
</configuration>
```

Só que quando o timeout acontece e eu entro no `Global.asax` no método `Session_End()`, eu não consigo ter acesso aos repositórios e nem ao `FormsAuthentication`.

Gostaria de saber o que tenho que fazer para repetir dentro do `Session_End()` exatamente o que eu faço ao clicar no botão de logoff. Alguém poderia ajudar?

## EDIT

Bom, acho que posso melhor elucidar o que busco. Busco desenvolver um meio de realizar um cadastro no banco de dados e a destruição do ticket de autenticação, da Session e do Cookie no momento que ocorre o TimeOut do tempo de inatividade.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depois de muita pesquisa, cheguei à conclusão que é impossível realizar *logoff* da forma que eu realizo no botão através do `Session_End()`. O jeito que eu arrumei para limpar o *cookie* depois do evento do *timeout*, foi realizando isso no `Session_Start()`

```
    protected void Session_Start()
        {
            try
            {
                var usuario = new SessionContext().GetUserData();

                if (usuario == null) return;

                Session.Clear(); //Pode não ser necessário, mas não é problemático o uso como prevenção
                Session.Abandon();

                //Limpar o cookie de Autenticação
                var resetFormsCookie = new HttpCookie(FormsAuthentication.FormsCookieName, "");
                resetFormsCookie.Expires = DateTime.Now.AddYears(-1);
                Response.Cookies.Add(resetFormsCookie);

                //Limpar a session cookie
                var resetSessionCookie = new HttpCookie("ASP.NET_SessionId", "");
                resetSessionCookie.Expires = DateTime.Now.AddYears(-1);
                Response.Cookies.Add(resetSessionCookie);

                //Invalida o Cache no lado do Cliente
                Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.NoCache);
                Response.Cache.SetNoStore();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                throw ex;
            }
            finally
            {
                Response.RedirectToRoute("Default");
            }
        }
```

E deixei o seguinte código no Session_End() como prevenção.

```
    protected void Session_End()
    {
        Session.Clear();
        Session.Abandon();
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Você pode redirecionar a requisição para uma rota que tenha acesso ao que você precisa:

```
protected void Session_End()
{
    Response.Clear(); 
    RouteData routeData = new RouteData(); 

    routeData.Values.Add("controller", "Account"); 
    routeData.Values.Add("action", "Login"); 

    IController AccountMainController = new AccountController(); 
    AccountMainController.Execute(new RequestContext( 
            new HttpContextWrapper(HttpContext.Current), routeData));
}
```

Comment: Olá Cigano. Bom tentei implementar o código que passaste só que eu recebi um erro no momento em que eu passo pelo Response.Clear(), HttpException: Resposta não está disponível neste contexto.
Além disso ao analisar o código creio que terei problemas ao instanciar o controller já que ele recebe por injeção dois parâmetros (usuarioApp e unitOfWorkAsync), que não tem como obter por aqui, pelo menos eu não sei como. Do mais agradeço pela ajuda.

Comment: Comente esta linha e veja se o resto funciona.

Comment: Na linha AccountMainController.Execute() ele deu a seguinte exceção: ArgumentNullException: Valor não pode ser nulo.
Nome do parâmetro: httpContext

Comment: @AlanBessa Atualizei a resposta.

Comment: Manteve a mesma exceção no mesmo lugar.
ArgumentNullException: "Valor não pode ser nulo. Nome do parâmetro: httpContext"

Comment: Não existe no ciclo de vida da aplicação, um evento que se dê no momento do fim da Sessão do Timeout no qual eu possa chamar meus métodos antes de fechar a sessão, não?

Comment: @AlanBessa O evento que eu conheço é este. Outra alternativa seria agendar um evento que verifique as sessões expiradas.